# Why throws a [ len() of unsized object ] if using a LIFT-metric score in xgboost?

Tags: python, xgboost

I wish to use a LIFT metric, using **`lift_score()`**, as the metric in `xgboost` tree model, then I set

```
.cv( ...,
     feval = lift_score,
     ...,
     )
```

but it shows the error:

> `TypeError: len() of unsized object`

It might be, because my dataset is of an **`int`** type, but `xgboost` tree only accepts integer data, not sure how to fix this problem.

Below is my code:

```
import xgboost as xgb
from mlxtend.evaluate import lift_score

t_params = { 'objective':       'binary:logistic',
             'eta':              0.1,
             'subsample':        0.8,
             'colsample_bytree': 0.8,                  
             'max_depth':        4,
             'min_child_weight': 6,
             'seed':             0,
              }
xgdmat = xgb.DMatrix( X_train, y_train )                # my data
cv_xgb = xgb.cv( params                =   t_params,
                 dtrain                =   xgdmat,
                 feval                 =   lift_score,
                 maximize              =   True,
                 num_boost_round       = 600,
                 nfold                 =   5,
                 early_stopping_rounds = 100
                 )
```

Comment: I would guess this is related to some problem in how your ```xgdmat``` is set up. Try investigating that and making sure its dimension and makeup are exactly as you expect them to be.

Comment: @dataprincess may I check what is makeup, thanks and I check the length already, they are the same..

Answer (score 0):

### Why? Well, the API expectations were not met:

While the **`feval`** parameter could be set freely, there are some expectations from the **`xgboost.cv()`** method API, that ought be fulfilled.

The **simpler part:**

> `# user defined evaluation function, return a pair metric_name, result`

so, your metric-evaluator function has to deliver a compatible result, best by:

```
return 'error', <_a_custom_LIFT_score_>
```

not meeting this requirement ( detected by testing if the `len( ... )` was at least 2 ), has actually ignited the above thrown **`TypeError`** exception. So this part is solved.

Next, the **harder part** to meet:

> <sub>( taken from the [source-code](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/demo/guide-python/custom_objective.py) )</sub>
>     # NOTE: when you do customized loss function, the default prediction value is margin
>       # this may make builtin evaluation metric not function properly
>       # for example, we are doing logistic loss, the prediction is score before logistic transformation
>       # the builtin evaluation error assumes input is after logistic transformation
>       # Take this in mind when you use the customization, and maybe you need write customized evaluation function

```
def evalerror(preds, dtrain): 
    labels = dtrain.get_label() 
    # return a pair metric_name, result 
    # since preds are margin(before logistic transformation, cutoff at 0) 
    return 'error', float(sum(labels != (preds > 0.0))) / len(labels)
```

---

### Call-interface matching issues:

```
def eval_LIFT( ModelPREDICTIONS, dtrain ):
    #                                 a thin wrapper to mediate conversion from
    #                                 Xgboost.cv() <feval>-FUN call-signature
    #                                 to a target lift_score() call-signature    
    return 'LIFT', lift_score( dtrain.get_label(),
                                ModelPREDICTIONS
                                )
```

because the **`mlxtend.evaluate.lift_score()`** call-signature does not match the `xgboost.cv()`-native parameter ordering, but has it's own one:

```
def lift_score( y_target,
                y_predicted,
                binary         = True,
                positive_label = 1
                ):
    """
    Lift measures the degree to which the predictions of a
    classification model are better than randomly-generated predictions.

    The in terms of True Positives (TP), True Negatives (TN),
    False Positives (FP), and False Negatives (FN), the lift score is
    computed as:

    [ TP/(TP+FN) ] / [ (TP+FP) / (TP+TN+FP+FN) ]
    ...
    """
    ...
```

the simple above wrapper will do the simpler part.

In case the `xgboost` walkthrough source-code warnings above, about the actual value-biases is to be implemented also for your LIFT-metric case, your value-adaptation step will have to take place inside the `eval_LIFT()`, before passing, now correctly adapted-values to the `mlxtend.evaluate.lift_score()` that expects un-biased values.